# how to check out AS source code

Tags: wso2, appserver, wso2-as

I want to check out the app server code, but don't know which repository I should check out. There are truck, branches, tags and many other repositories.

Which repository is AS 5.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

For AS 5.2.0 it should be this.

http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk01/products/as/5.2.0/

You need to get the `tag` as it contains the unmodified code of the released product.

Comment: thanks, Nutail. what if I want to follow the latest code? So which branch I can check? And I see truck02 and 03. Are they based on other version of Carbon?

Answer (score 0):

you can check out the chunk01 release to get the AS 5.2.0 [1]. you should find AS under products->as. hope this helps :)

[1] http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk01/

Comment: Thanks pulasthi. This helps. And I also want to check out the latest code, so that I can follow your step :) and Carbon 4.2 is called 'turing' ?

Comment: yes we have changed the naming conventions and 4.2.0 is called turing :). http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/ is the working branch for turing. release's are done as chunks as you can see in the tags.

Comment: Hi, I see AS repository is almost empty, but I see components/application-mgt/ consists of codes that I can find in the AS plugins folder.  I wonder which components I should check out if I want to see the whole picture of AS, at least I want to debug or learn how the code stream goes on. Can you show me how you manage your dev job through IDE? :D

Comment: Its not easy to just checkout each component you need. You can check out the whole chunk01 and then open the component you need from your ide and debug using remote debug. its not easy to understand the product by looking at each component separately